# Unable to set angular variable inside callback

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript, directions

I'm using the google maps directions service to calculate the travel time.

```
this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
  const p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(50.926217, 5.342043);
  const p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(50.940525, 5.353626);

  const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  const request = {
    origin: p1,
    destination: p2,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
  };

  directionsService.route(request, (response, status) => {

    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      const point = response.routes[0].legs[0];
      // console.log(point.duration.text);
      this.travelTimeDriving = point.duration.text;
    }
  });


});
```

The console logs the correct driving time, but my variable this.travelTimeDriving stays empty.
I guess it had something to do with the callback function and scope but I can't fix it.
Also the route function returns void, no promise so I can't use .then()

Comment: can you pls explain why you downvote?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use NgZone to make sure the callback will be bind to the scope. Working sample:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
declare const google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  travelTimeDriving = '';

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

    const p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(50.926217, 5.342043);
    const p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(50.940525, 5.353626);

    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    const request = {
      origin: p1,
      destination: p2,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    };

    directionsService.route(request, (response, status) => this.ngZone.run(() => {

      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        const point = response.routes[0].legs[0];
        this.travelTimeDriving = point.duration.text;
      }
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: and when/how do I assign it to my global variable this.travelTimeDriving so I can use it in my html {{travelTimeDriving }} ?

Comment: I'm running a sandbox to reply this problem, but for now, have you tried `import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';` So you can call `directionsService.route(request, (response, status)).toPromise().then()` ?

Comment: that sounds like a good solution but I get this error: Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'void'

Comment: There you go, I was able to reproduce your problem. The solution is above.

Comment: Nice to hear, I will upvote your question. But change the title, I believe the reason for the downvote is the title doesn't correspond to the real problem.

Comment: do you have any suggestions for the title? I don't know how to explain this problem correctly

Comment: _Unable to set angular variable inside callback_ maybe. This problem is not related to google maps nor directions service.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right about your scope not being what you expect it to be.
Depending on what editor/IDE you use this should give you an error when referencing

```
this.travelTimeDriving = point.duration.text;
```

if your scope is incorrect/the variable is not declared in the scope you expect. To me it looks like you should be referencing the class members, do you have that variable declared in your class (that calls this function) ?

I would assume if you were to log the value right after you set it you would see the result.

```
 if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  const point = response.routes[0].legs[0];
  // console.log(point.duration.text);
  this.travelTimeDriving = point.duration.text;
  console.log(this.travelTimeDriving);
}
```

You should be able to figure out the scope "this" has at that point by either console.log it or set a breakpoint and inspect the value.

If you can share more of the surrounding code it would be easier to help you get closer.

Comment: I declared the variable in the same class, travelTimeDriving: string;

Comment: when I log like in your examples it is logging the correct value, strange

Comment: when I log 'this' it logs the current component so that should be correct

Comment: when I set this.travelTimeDriving outside of directionsService.route(), it's working but at this point I don't yet have the point.duration.text value

Comment: if the route() function would just return a promise that would be nice

Comment: (response, status) => { <code> } is a callback that .route function calls for you when its finished. It serves the same purpose as .then it's just another way of abstracting the async flow of the code.

So the "component" you mention is an instance of the class you declared the variable in? 

I suspect it's your timing of trying to use the variable that is off. When are you trying to use the value / how do you trigger the next step?

Comment: I just want to display this.travelTimeDriving in my html, {{travelTimeDriving}}

Comment: I see. What kind of databinder do you use? Angular? 

As long as the HTML is rendered/databound after the route call is finished it should work as you expect. But if you try to use it on pageload or anytime before the route call has finished it will databind a blank value.

Comment: yes this is angular 5, I know, I fixed it with a timeout but that's just a dirty hack, I guess I need to use a subject or something but I don't really understand how to use it

Comment: I haven't used Angular since it was called AngularJS so I can't help with that unfortunately. You should mention databinding in angular5  in your question, I am sure more people will be able to help then.

Instead of a timeout you could create a function that updates it for you and then call that when the route call is finished.

Comment: thanks, the problem is I don't know how to detect when the call is finished, that would indeed be the solution